# Override the loading animation of fancybox 2

Tags: javascript, fancybox-2

I have a fancybox 2 .pdf loader working that loads into an iframe.  Some PDFs take a little time to render before being sent and I wanted to use the [spin.js spinner](http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/) as a progress bar as the animation is loaded instead of the supplied .gif

i can start the animation up easily enough using the beforeShow event, but i can't see which event to trap when the object is returned from the server.  i have tried all events in [the documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs), but i can't see one that traps when the pdf is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

you might need to stop the current event and tell it to execute the next function of hiding the spinner

not sure what the id of the spinner is but using jQuery you can

```
$('#spinner').stop(true,true).hide();
```

which should stop any current events and cut to the end so you can instantly start a new function on it

Comment: Thanks tgammage, but that is how to stop the spinner, which i can do. how do i know **when** to stop the spinner?  ie what event triggers the code you wrote?